# Live Persistant Install Won't Boot

Tags: boot, live-usb, init, persistence

I've installed Ubuntu on a flash drive via UNetbootin and it worked flawlessly up until today. A few moments after I booted it said "System Problem Detected" and I reported it. I disregarded this since it happens nearly every time I boot but this time the screen glitched out and I forced it down to reboot. Now the problem. I get the UNetbootin menu and then the splash screen comes up and then a black screen.

Booting without splash shows two errors that I can see, mostly a series of input/output errors related to casper, errors in the EXT2-fs, and init reporting 'caught abort, core dumped'

I'm not too worried about saving the installation, but I do have notes from a class that are very important to me and I'd like to save those if possible.

Hopefully I've given enough information to help...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your USB stick is going bad.  Stop trying to boot it, it will only get worse.  All your files are in a file named casper-rw, which you should copy off the stick.  That file may be mounted with the loop option and will look like a whole filesystem, with parts missing.  The present parts are the changes made, so your files should be in /mnt//home//...   Copy off what you need.  Then you can see if the stick is salvagable.